# Prestashop 1.7 add <br> special character tag in category name but invalid , how to split string in menu navigation nav?

Tags: php, prestashop, smarty, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

A lot of people are having a similar problem for adding a hashtag in the product name. I am trying to add a 
 tag ( html line break ) in the **category name**. I have put "Category 
 name" for example, it won't work. The character validation is there for security measures, it makes sense.

So I have tried to overwrite the file "Validate.php" , as explained on another topic by redefining the isCatalogName function like so :

```
<?php
class Validate extends ValidateCore
{

    public static function isCatalogName($name)
    {
        // simple test
        
        return !preg_match('/[]/i', $name);
        
    }
}
```

now I should be able to put a hashtag like `#` , or `<br />` like I wanted, but still get the error.

I have tried different ways :

- overwriting only the file "Validate.php"
- overwriting Validate.php, but also Category.php and CMSCategory.php where the function "isCatalogName($name)" is called and removing the validation in these files.
- I cleared cache in back-end and also var/cache files to be sure each time, logged out / logged in administration every time. Refreshed browser cache / Changed browser too !

Any ideas on how to have a split string ( 2 lines menu navigation link ) in the category name on Prestashop 1.7 ?

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after looking around and asking on the Prestashop forums, I've been told there is no easy-straightforward-hack-free solution to achieve this. Because apparently the name chosen for the category is used to construct the url. This would mean editing many core files just to put a special character via the back-end>categories fields, which is illogic.

So I just hardcoded this into the file `modules\ps_mainmenu\*ps_mainmenu.tpl*` : it works for my case.

```
 {* {$node.label} *}


               {if $node.label|strstr:"and"}
                  {assign var="teststring" value=$node.label}
                  {assign var="testsplit" value="and"|explode:$teststring}
                  {$testsplit[0]} <br/> and {$testsplit[1]}
              
                  {elseif $node.label|strstr:","}

                  {if substr_count($node.label, ",") > 1 }

                    {assign var="teststring" value=$node.label}

                    {assign var="label" value=","|explode:$teststring}

                    {$label[0]},<br/>{$label[1]}, {$label|@end}
                    

                  {/if}
```

I'm sure someone PHP/Smarty savy could do this in a few lines and much nicer ( let me know please! ) but it works for me. (adding `<br/>` in some cases)